Pandas dataframe add new column for a update date on all rows
Is there a simple way to add a new column to a Pandas dataframe to hold an update date or record creation date for all the rows in the dataframe?
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name' : 'a','widget' : 25},{'name' : 'b', 'widget' : 26},{'name' : 'c', 'widget' : 20}],index=[0,1,2])

Result:
    name  widget
0   a      25
1   b      26
2   c      20

new dataframe with date the df was created
    name  widget  update_dt
0   a      25      09/05/2024 15:45
1   b      26      09/05/2024 15:45
2   c      20      09/05/2024 15:45


df['update_dt'] = '09/05/2024 15:45'
